# Error When Clicking - Add Another Item - An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally

Tags: forms

On drupal 7, I have a problem with a form. Render content type form in drupal 7 everthing working fine but

I created a Field Collection, when I click Add another item 
this error occurs

```
/************Error************/
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /system/ajax
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: ShareEmailFacebookTwitterGoogle+PinterestLinkedInStumbleUponRedditGoogle BookmarksWordPressTumblrDeliciousDiggMySpaceYahoo BookmarksBeboMister-WongApp.netWaneloOrkutXINGBufferEvernoteWhatsAppMendeleyPocketVKPinboardSpringpadFlipboardArtoAIMYahoo MessengerPlurkDiasporaBlogger PostTypePad PostBox.netKindle ItBaiduNetlogCiteULikeJumptagsFunPInstapaperPhoneFavsXerpiNetvouzDiigoBibSonomyBlogMarksStartAidKhabbrMeneameYoolinkBookmarks.frTechnotizieNewsVineFriendFeedProtopage BookmarksBlinklistYiGGWebnewsSegnaloPushaYouMobSlashdotFarkAllvoicesJamespotTwiddlaLinkaGoGoNowPublicLiveJournalLinkatopiaBuddyMarksViadeoWistsSiteJotDZoneCare2 NewsBitty BrowserOdnoklassnikiMail.RuSymbaloo FeedsFolkdNewsTrustAmazon Wish ListPrintFriendlyTuentiEmailRediff MyPageGoogle GmailYahoo MailOutlook.comAOL MailAny email&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;By AddToAny
We Are Working On Riley Drupal
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
ReadyState: undefined
/************Error************/

function customurl_menu() {
   $items = array();
    $items['program/%/register'] = array(
          'title'            => t('Add @node_type', array('@node_type' => t('Node Type'))),
          'page callback'    => 'drupal_get_form',
          'page arguments'   => array('module_node_add_form', 'registration'),
          'access arguments' => array('administer nodes'),
          'file path'        => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
          'file'             => 'node.pages.inc',
          'type'             => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
          'weight'           => 1,
          ); 
    return $items;
}
function module_node_add_form ($form, &$form_state, $node_type) {
    global $user;
    //if( !function_exists("node_form")) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    //}
    //if( !function_exists("field_collection_item_form_validate")) {
    module_load_include('inc', 'field_collection', 'field_collection.pages');
    // }
    $node = (object) array(
    'uid' => $user->uid,
    'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
    'type' => $node_type,
    'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
    );

    node_object_prepare($node);
    $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
    form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = drupal_retrieve_form($node_type . '_node_form', $form_state);
    drupal_prepare_form($node_type . '_node_form', $form, $form_state);
    return $form;

}
```

i tryed this links https://www.drupal.org/node/1299074

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You aren't asking any explicit question, but merely stating facts. Keep in mind we cannot debug a site to which we don't have access.